# Getting the height of Keyboard on Android

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, keyboard

Hi I need to know the height of my keyboard so I can move up some textfield I have in my app. I'm using cocos2D-X but the app don't recognize the keyboardWillShow method.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of the virtual keyboard, you can't get the height. What you can do is set your window to re-size mode and handle the re-size.

For more information see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009487/get-the-height-of-virtual-keyboard-in-android) on SO and [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/82VetotWeik) on Google groups.

Comment: Sorry, how can I set my window to re-size ? I found this android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" but it doesn't work

Comment: And in the stack forum I can't get getSingletonInstrumentation() so it doesn't work for me neither

Comment: Sorry, I can't help much beyond what I've given you. I've never written an Android app. What I read says that strategy will work, but I can't give you the specifics of implementing it.